# Registering gradients in logo as a trademark?

Tags: logo, copyright, branding, trademark

When registering a logo as a trademark, how does one register the gradient colors? Is it just the start and the finish of the gradient colors? Or is it best to turn the logo into a solid color logo and give the minimal sections of colors?

Comment: This si a legal question and depends on country/region you are in.

Answer (score 2):

What is registred as a trademark is the logo, no its "accidents".

The proper way to make a logo is to design a distinctive shape with meaning (or not), not necessary its colors; far less a gradient.

A logo can be in white, on one ink, or full color depending on the situation, but that does not imply it is a diferent logo or trademark.

If the documentatnion requires it probably you need to document colors as part of the description, but a color is not part of a trademark.

Sometimes (depending on the country or type of registration) a full sticker or label can be documented, so you simply provide a phisical sample.

---

P.S. A gradient as an intrinsec part of a logo, in my opinion is a mistake. If someone as an ilustrator starts putting effects, explosions, gradients, shadows, and after that, you need to strip the image to find the base logo below... the process is backwards.

Comment: I think rickjames had in mind something like with Mercedes-Benz. Their gradient is registered as a part of their brand identity. But what is trademarked is two specific colors that go from one specific point on the page under specific angle to another color.